# Deploy JRuby on Rails to AWS EC2 with Rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, jruby, jrubyonrails, rubber

I am trying to deploy a basic JRuby on Rails app to EC2 using Rubber. I am following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2?view=asciicast) guide and the only difference is that I'm using JRuby.

Is this possible? Can I use one of the provided templates (for example complete_passenger_postgresql) with JRuby?

I see that the rubber-ruby.yml file has a line where you can specify the ruby_version. Do I need to specify that I want to use JRuby?

Is there a different template that I should be using?

At the moment I am getting the following error when I try the command 'cap rubber:create_staging'

> NoMethodError: undefined method `readLine' for nil:NilClass
>                                get_line at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/highline-1.7.2/lib/highline.rb:863
>                            get_response at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/highline-1.7.2/lib/highline.rb:891
>                                     ask at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/highline-1.7.2/lib/highline.rb:264
>                                 get_env at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/rubber-3.0.1/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/utils.rb:191
>                                  (eval) at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/rubber-3.0.1/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/utils.rb:17
>                           instance_eval at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1641
>                    invoke_task_directly at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138
>     invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25
>                            execute_task at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89
>                   find_and_execute_task at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101
>               execute_requested_actions at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:46
>                                    each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1569
>               execute_requested_actions at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45
>     execute_requested_actions_with_help at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/help.rb:19
>                                execute! at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:34
>                                 execute at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14
>                                  (root) at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/bin/cap:4
>                                    load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:969
>                                  (root) at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/bin/cap:1
>                                    eval at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:990
>                              **script** at /Users/pk/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1/bin/jruby_executable_hooks:15

Answer (score 0):

**jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1** is a pre-release, since there's another **pre2** please try that, if that does not work out you should check if things work with latest jruby-1.7.x before reporting an issue.